# How to just get data of other branch which is not in master branch

Tags: git, github

I stuck with a situation where I merged `staging` into `master` branch but some files and content of some files from `staging` is missing in `master` branch (This happens because of some issue created in our `master` branch which other member fix by editing the code).

I made a diff of both branches and it shows lot of differences.

Now what I want is to get only data and files missing in `master` and don't want to lose the content of `master` which is not in `staging`.

Comment: Just generate a patch from the diff and apply it to master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git diff --diff-filter D --name-only staging master
```

will list the files that are present in staging, and missing in master.

---

You can then call `git checkout staging <file>` on some individual files, or :

```
git diff --diff-filter D --name-only staging master | xargs git checkout staging
```

to get them all.